# Filter WPF DataGrid C# Populated by MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, datagrid

I would like to filter my DataGrid as a user is typing into a search box. I bind my data to my DataGrid by the following;

In my DataAccessor;

```
    public DataTable FillDataGrid()
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbfString"].ConnectionString;
        using (OleDbConnection dbfCon = new OleDbConnection(constr))
        {
            try
            {
                dbfCon.Open();
                DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
                string dbfQuery = "SELECT em_pplid, em_name, em_netname, em_init, em_dept FROM employs WHERE em_netname NOT LIKE ''";
                OleDbCommand MyQuery = new OleDbCommand(dbfQuery, dbfCon);
                OleDbDataAdapter DA = new OleDbDataAdapter(MyQuery);
                DA.Fill(dTable);
                return dTable;
            }
            catch (OleDbException)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

And in my View;

```
    private void FillDataGrid(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataAccessor da = new DataAccessor();
        DataTable dt = da.FillDataGrid();
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView();
    }
```

Also in my view I currently have this that is ready to be a search function when I know how to properly filter the DataGrid;

```
    private void SearchGrid(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (nNameRad.IsChecked == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
        }
    }
```

I have searched online and found quite a few seemingly outdated methods of filtering the DataGrid. How can I do this in my program?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should not really bind you raw data to the view. Create a custom class that represents your data, and access it as any other normal C# object. That way you can separate your data from your view, and approach a MVVM pattern. For example, you data class can provide the filter method. Nobody else than the data class should really know how to filter itself.

Once you have done that, filtering a ListBox, DataGrid, or whatever ItemControl you happen to use, is really simple. Here is a simple code that does the basics. Provide your own way to get data instead of a static constructor, and you have something you can work further on.

MyFirstData.cs

```
public class MyFirstData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Filter(string filterText)
    {
        return Id.ToString() == filterText || Name.Contains(filterText);
    }
}
```

MainWindow.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Items = new ObservableCollection<MyFirstData>()
        {
            new MyFirstData() {Id = 1, Name = "foo"},
            new MyFirstData() {Id = 2, Name = "bar"},
            new MyFirstData() {Id = 3, Name = "marble"},
        };
        ItemsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Items);

        DataContext = this;
    }

    private string _filterText;

    public string FilterText
    {
        get { return _filterText; }
        set
        {
            _filterText = value;
            ItemsView.Filter = DoFilter;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool DoFilter(object obj)
    {
        var myFirstData = obj as MyFirstData;
        if (myFirstData != null)
        {
            return myFirstData.Filter(FilterText);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyFirstData> Items { get; set; }
    public ICollectionView ItemsView { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="FilterTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FilterTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding FilterText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsView}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="local:MyFirstData">
                    <TextBlock>
                        <Run Text="{Binding Id}"/>
                        <Run Text=", "/>
                        <Run Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```